# Pushing an array in a for loop javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays I am trying to push, one called potential Word and one allword. allword is a global, and potential is in the function.I only want to push allword on the first pass of the code, so I have the variable pusher, so it will not run again after one run. Only potentialWord will.

the problem is that allwords never sends any data back, while potential word does Even when pusher is 0.

```
for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
  potentialWord.push(info[i].word);
  while (pusher = 0){
    allwords.push(info[i].word);
  }
}
pusher +=1;
```

I would like for info to be pushed to both arrays, then after my function is called again, only potential word is pushed while allwords remains the same.

Thank You!

Comment: share your info data and expected result too.

Comment: When does your while-loop stop?

Comment: Your while loop needs 2 fixes. 1) change to `while (pusher === 0)` and 2) Provide a way for the loop to exit.

Comment: Thank you, I changed pusher to == 0 and made it a for loop so it terminates and it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo here

```
while (pusher = 0)
```

Should be

```
while (pusher === 0)
```

or

```
while (pusher == 0)
```

**Explanation**

You should be doing a comparison, which is using `===` or `==`.

Instead the typo used assignment, which is `=`.

`while (pusher = 0)` will always returns falsy. Because `pusher = 0` expression returns `0`, which will be evaluated to `false` in JavaScript.

Therefore, the while loop has never run. So, `allwords` is empty.